# Knights of the Square Sudoku Table

Tags: grid-deduction, sudoku

```
 8  .  . | .  .  . | .  .  6 
 .  .  4 | .  .  . | .  .  . 
 .  .  . | .  .  . | 9  1  . 
---------+---------+--------
 .  .  . | .  2  . | .  .  . 
 .  .  9 | 3  .  . | .  .  . 
 .  .  . | .  .  . | .  .  . 
---------+---------+--------
 .  .  . | 9  .  7 | .  .  . 
 9  .  . | 6  3  . | 4  .  . 
 .  .  . | .  .  . | 1  .  .
```

- Normal sudoku rules apply.
- Long diagonals contain only unique values.
- If A is a box-center, and A and B are a knight's move apart, then A and B ought to be different.

A *knight's move* constitutes going up/down by two followed by going left/right by one, or going up/down by one followed by going left/right by two:

```
. . B . B . .
. B . . . B .
. . . A . . .
. B . . . B .
. . B . B . .
```

Comment: Does "diagonals" mean just the two long diagonals, or every line at 45 degrees? [EDITED to add:] Duh, must be the former since there are two diagonally-adjacent 1s in the grid already.

Comment: It looks like the 9s in R2C4 and R4C5 contradict the pseudo-knight move restriction. Is that intended?

Comment: The same with 5 at the top right.

Comment: I believe this is unsolvable. I've tried twice to solve it deterministically, both times resulting in contradictions. Are you able to check that a solution exists satisfying the conditions?

Comment: The puzzle should be solvable now. I updated the puzzle itself and the instructions. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The 9s (on 3rd and 4th column) now are contradicting, is this also intended?

Comment: The knight move constraint only applies for a cell that is the center of a 3x3 square

Comment: Okay I cheated: if I assume that each box-centre contains a different digit from 1 to 9 then Jens' answer is indeed the unique solution. But this assumption is not correct (we can place a 3 in r2c2 and threes don't break).

The only alternative is the Feigenbaum method: keep bifurcating and bifurcating and bifurcating and hope to solve it before the time limit of 4.669201619 hours is up. But that is left as an exercise for the reader  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very tough Sudoku, but I think I got it:

> [image]

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Well done. Can you show your working to prove this solution is unique? (I've seen some dud puzzles on PSE but I have to give OP the benefit of the doubt until proven otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

(1) the 9s in columns 3 and 4 contradict the knight's-move restriction.

(2) a 9 cannot be placed in the middle 3x3.

- column 4 has already a 9 in row 7.
- the two spaces in column 5 are both restricted by the 9 in column 3 (same row and knight's move).
- r4c6 is in a main diagonal that already contains a 9 in column 7.
- r5c6 is within a row with a 9 in column 3.
- r6c6 is within knight's move from 9 in c4

there must be an error in the initial values.[image]

Comment: But the puzzle's criterion states "**If A is a box-center**, and A and B are a knight's move apart, then A and B ought to be different." The knight's move element is only relevant for box-centre-positioned numbers. Numbers in other spaces are not constrained by this. With this in mind, I don't think your objection holds... Please correct me if I'm wrong :)